# Umbraco 8 backoffice login with IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, identityserver4, umbraco8

**Background**

I'm quite new to Umbraco but have been trying to use [IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) for the BackOffice of Umbraco.
For the IDP, I've used the in-memory configuration (is4inmem template) found [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Templates).

For Umbraco I've used the [UmbracoIdentityExtensions](https://github.com/umbraco/UmbracoIdentityExtensions) to configure OpenId Connect.

I've been mainly following [this](https://yuriburger.net/2017/04/26/login-to-umbraco-backoffice-using-identityserver4/) tutorial (this is however, for Umbraco 7).

**The problem**

I do have the 'Sign in with OpenId connect' button which I configured, but when I try to log in using the IDP, Umbraco does not log me in. I keep getting returned to the login page.
Whenever I go to the IDP page, however, I am logged in and can see I've given access as seen in the picture below.
[image]

Whenever I log in with an Umbraco account, and then try to 'Link your OpenId Connect account', it does nothing, but upon logging out an error message appears in the screen: 'An error occurred, could not get external login info'
I've tried to use different configuration settings, but without success.

**Code**

IDP Config.cs

```
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> Ids =>
            new IdentityResource[]
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
                new IdentityResources.Email(),
                new IdentityResource(
                    name: "application.profile",
                    displayName: "Application profile",
                    claimTypes: new[] { ClaimTypes.GivenName, ClaimTypes.Surname }
                )
            };

... etc ...

 public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new Client[]
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "u-client-bo",
                    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256()),
                    },
                    ClientName = "Umbraco Client",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    RedirectUris           = { "https://localhost:44302/Umbraco" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44302/Umbraco" },
                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        "application.profile",
                    },
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = false
                }
            };
```

For Umbraco, I have edited the *UmbracoCustomOwinStartup* to the following:

```
public class UmbracoCustomOwinStartup : UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup
{
    protected override void ConfigureUmbracoUserManager(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.ConfigureUserManagerForUmbracoBackOffice(
            Services,
            Mapper,
            UmbracoSettings.Content,
            GlobalSettings,

            global::Umbraco.Core.Security.MembershipProviderExtensions.GetUsersMembershipProvider().AsUmbracoMembershipProvider());
    }

    protected override void ConfigureUmbracoAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app
            .UseUmbracoBackOfficeCookieAuthentication(UmbracoContextAccessor, RuntimeState, Services.UserService, GlobalSettings, UmbracoSettings.Security, PipelineStage.Authenticate)
            .UseUmbracoBackOfficeExternalCookieAuthentication(UmbracoContextAccessor, RuntimeState, GlobalSettings, PipelineStage.Authenticate)
            .UseUmbracoPreviewAuthentication(UmbracoContextAccessor, RuntimeState, GlobalSettings, UmbracoSettings.Security, PipelineStage.Authorize);

        var identityOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "u-client-bo",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
            Authority = "https://localhost:44393",
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44302/Umbraco",
            ResponseType = "code id_token token",
            Scope = "openid profile application.profile",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44302/Umbraco",

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = ClaimsTransformer.GenerateUserIdentityAsync
            }
        };

        // Configure BackOffice Account Link button and style
        identityOptions.ForUmbracoBackOffice("btn-microsoft", "fa-windows");
        identityOptions.Caption = "OpenId Connect";

        // Configure AutoLinking
        identityOptions.SetExternalSignInAutoLinkOptions(
            new ExternalSignInAutoLinkOptions(autoLinkExternalAccount: true));

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(identityOptions);
    }
}
```

The *ClaimsTransformer.GenerateUserIdentityAsync* method adds additional claims to the Identity.

Am I missing additional configuration or components?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you share your identityserver's log with us? it seems your configuration need some changes.

Comment: @Mehrdad Thank you for responding. I've uploaded the log to https://pastebin.com/QhSBcEuj

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't find anything from the log too. thank you for share.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've finally figured it out. There were several issues:

**1. Correct the auth cookie**

Instead of using `DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie` as `SignInAsAuthenticationType` , I am now using `Umbraco.Core.Constants.Security.BackOfficeExternalAuthenticationType`.

**2. Set the AuthenticationType**

Set the `AuthenticationType` in the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`. It must match the name of the `Authority` in order for auto-link to work.

**Important**: Set it again after `identityOptions.ForUmbracoBackOffice("btn-microsoft", "fa-windows");` explicitly since it prefixes it with `'Umbraco.'` after the method call.

**3. Include the email claim**

I've added the email claim, this is also required for auto-link to work.

`Scope = "openid email profile application.profile",`

**4. Ensure that you have any form of name claim**

I've set `AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken` to `true` in the IDP, so the id claims get automatically in Umbraco.
My `ClaimsTransformer` looks like this now:

```cs
public class ClaimsTransformer
{
    public static async Task GenerateUserIdentityAsync(
        SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        // Now this contains ID claims (e.g. GivenName in my case)
        var id = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

        var identityUser = new ClaimsIdentity(
            id.Claims, // copy the claims I have
            notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType,
            // set the nameType, so Umbraco can use the 'ExternalLogin.Name' for auto-link to work
            ClaimTypes.GivenName, // <-- You have to set a correct nameType claim
            ClaimTypes.Role);

         notification.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(identityUser,
                notification.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
    }
}
```

**5. Remove other Umbraco Auth middleware**

The `app.UseUmbracoBackOfficeXXX` statements were not needed in my case, in fact, they broke the functionality. My `UmbracoCustomOwinStartup` looks like this now:

```cs
public class UmbracoCustomOwinStartup : UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup
{
    protected override void ConfigureUmbracoAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        base.ConfigureUmbracoAuthentication(app);

        var identityOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "u-client-bo",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = Umbraco.Core.Constants.Security.BackOfficeExternalAuthenticationType,
            AuthenticationType = "https://localhost:44393",
            Authority = "https://localhost:44393",
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44302/Umbraco",
            ResponseType = "code id_token token",
            Scope = "openid email profile application.profile",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44302/Umbraco",

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = ClaimsTransformer.GenerateUserIdentityAsync
            }
        };

        // Configure BackOffice Account Link button and style
        identityOptions.ForUmbracoBackOffice("btn-microsoft", "fa-windows");
        identityOptions.Caption = "OpenId Connect";

        identityOptions.AuthenticationType = "https://localhost:44393";

        // Configure AutoLinking
        identityOptions.SetExternalSignInAutoLinkOptions(
            new ExternalSignInAutoLinkOptions(autoLinkExternalAccount: true));

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(identityOptions);
    }

}
```

tip: Don't forget to use the correct OWIN Startup in your `web.config`.

I hope some of you found this helpful, I couldn't find alot of documentation about Umbraco 8 in combination with IdentityServer4.